# Convert object from a type to another by casting using java Field getType() method

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I am using ksoap2, and when I get a soap object  that looks like:

```
params=anyType
{
  defaultValueString=10; 
  label=Number of search results; 
  optional=true; 
  PRName=Yahoo PR; 
  paramName=limit; 
  pipelineName=Yahoo Search; 
  type=int; 
};
```

I try to change some fields in class using reflection, by using method `setAttr`:

The `setAttr` method is written:

```
public void setAttr(Object tag,Object value)
{
    Field dynamicSet = gateRuntimeParameter.class.getField((String)tag);

    dynamicSet.set(new gateRuntimeParameter(),  value);

}
```

The problem is tag would sometimes be lets say: boolean, but value is an `soapprimitve` object type...

How can I cast value using field `getType`, i.e. something like: `(dynamicSet.getType())value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write custom coercion code to do this. Trying to simply cast the value won't be possible, since it would require rules to handle cases like casting `boolean` to `int`. You'll need to write a method something like this:

```
public Object coerce(Object value, Class<?> coerceTo) {
    if (Boolean.class.equals(coerceTo)) {
        //coerce soap primitive to Boolean
    }
    else if (Integer.class.equals(coerceTo)) {
        //coerce soap primitive to Integer
    }
    else if (List.class.equals(coerceTo)) {
      return Collections.singletonList(coerce(value, coerceTo.getTypeParameters()[0]));
    }
}
```

Note that java's auto-boxing/unboxing will mean you don't need to worry about handling the `int` case separately to `java.lang.Integer`, just handle `java.lang.Integer` and java will auto-coerce to `int` if required.

Comment: thx for the help, but how do you coerce in a case where you have a type: List<Object> ??

Comment: @Chadic Hm, I think something like this might work, but untested `if (List.class.equals(dynamicSet.getType())) { return Collections.singletonList(coerce(value, dynamicSet.getType().getTypeParameters()[0])); }`. You'll probably want to factor out your coerce method so it can take the Class type to coerce to as a parameter, then you can recurse onto it for `Collection` types. I think `dynamicSet.getType().getTypeParameters()[0]` should give the generic type declared on your method (if you've declared them).

Comment: @Chadic I've updated the original answer to give you a clearer idea of how to handle collection types. It's untested, I'm not sure if type erasure will prevent this from working, but it's worth a try.

Comment: thx a lot man , it works ( i still didnt test the list part but i will soon) :)